# BoxPlot Charting on Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mschart, boxplot

I am working on a project that processes data and displays information using Boxplot Chart in Visual Studio 2010 using C/C++ language.

I found some examples on [MSDN Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456709%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) but it only includes sample codes in C# and Visual Basic, but I couldn't find examples in C/C++ language.

I tried to create a boxplot using this code

```
this->chart1->Series["dat"]->Points->AddY(10);
this->chart1->Series["dat"]->Points->AddY(5);
this->chart1->Series["dat"]->Points->AddY(7);
this->chart1->Series["dat"]->Points->AddY(4);
this->chart1->Series["dat"]->Points->AddY(8);
this->chart1->Series["dat"]->Points->AddY(6);
```

But instead of showing a single boxplot (as below)

```
---------
    |
    |
  -----
 |     |
  -----
 |     |
  -----
    |
    |
---------
```

it displays 6 different whiskers

```
 ---                 ---
  |   ---  ---        |   ---
  |    |    |   ---   |    |
  |    |    |    |    |    |
 ---  ---  ---  ---  ---  ---
```

I tried to manipulate C++ instructions in order to create a code similar to the sample code within the MSDN documentation and insert data into the chart, so I tried this:

```
this->chart1->Series["dat"]->Points->AddY(10);
this->chart1->Series["dat"]->Points->AddY(5);
this->chart1->Series["dat"]->Points->AddY(7);
this->chart1->Series["dat"]->Points->AddY(4);
this->chart1->Series["dat"]->Points->AddY(8);
this->chart1->Series["dat"]->Points->AddY(6);
this->chart1->Series["BoxPlotSeries"]["BoxPlotSeries"]="dat";
```

But it didn't work.

It is kind of difficult for me to explore the Chart methods and properties as VS2010 does not provide Intellisense for C++/CLI.

Could you provide me any sample code to create Boxplot Charts for Visual C++ 2010??? Any ideas???

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
System::Windows::Forms::DataVisualization::Charting::Series^ bpSeries = 
    gcnew System::Windows::Forms::DataVisualization::Charting::Series();
bpSeries->Name = "bpSeries";

std::vector<int> yValues { 10,5,7,4,8,6 };

for(int i = 0; i < yValues.size(); i++)
    bpSeries->Points->AddY(yValues[i]);

this->chart1->Series["dat"]["BoxPlotSeries"] = "bpSeries";
```